# How to write a wrapper function for open, which takes variable number of arguments?

Tags: c, system-calls, variadic

I want to implement a wrapper over the open system call, and I'm using the LD_PRELOAD trick to call my new open.

The problem is that open expects a variable number of arguments, and I cannot figure out how to call open with the same set of arguments, as open cannot take a va_list pointer as an argument(or I do not know of any such function).

How could I achieve this?

code so far:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

typedef int (*open_func_t)(const char*, int, ...)

int open(const char *pathname, int flags, ...){
    // some custom code

    // what args should I supply to dlsym?
    return ((open_func_t)dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open"))(args);
}
```

Comment: Then why not make your `open` wrapper accept `va_list*`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Shouldn't my wrapper expect the exact same args as the call itself?

Comment: Process `flags` like `open()` and then call your function with 2 or 3 parameters.  [open](https://linux.die.net/man/3/open)

Comment: Yes, that's probably what I'll end up doing if nothing else works.

Comment: @Tanmay Sachan The code you show here that use `dlsym`, does jt call syscall `open` or your wrapper? I am confused

Comment: If you are calling your wrapper `open`, then you can consider changing your function to a macro and put the "custom code " in this `open` to another function.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu dlsym with RTLD_NEXT would call the syscall open and not my implementation of open.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance.